# excluding file in commit - ignore file in git (.gitignore)

Tags: git

I have a file named `iConstructor.v11.suo` which I wan't to ignore with commits, tried multiple ways, but it is still in my unstaged changes..
I can ignore other folders, but have problem with this file

tried this in *.gitignore*:

```
# git ignore file
iConstructor.v11.suo

\iConstructor.v11.suo
*\iConstructor.v11.suo
*iConstructor.v11.suo

/iConstructor.v11.suo
*/iConstructor.v11.suo
/*.suo
\*.suo
**\*.suo
**/*.*.suo
*.v11.suo/
```

I guess the problem is that I just started the repository over the old project: first started the "iConstructor" (empty) repository and then copied my files, so the main folder structure looks like this:
|
|- .gitignore
|- iConstructor
|- other iConstructor-project directories
|- iConstructor.v11.suo
|- ...

Comment: have you tired 'git rm --cached iConstructor.v11.suo'?

Comment: did just now, it works!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have it working with the line *.suo in my .gitignore file. If it's not working for you, this may work for you :

> git rm --cached iConstructor.v11.suo